# .NET Framework updater component and WPF

Tags: wpf, deployment, setup-deployment, auto-update

I'm trying to do add an auto-updater to a wpf application of mine and liked [this article](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx)
 and i've tried to add the updater component to the toolbox of the VS 2008 that i'm using but it seems it cannot be added to the wpf project toolbox.I doubt i would see it the wpf project toolbox even though i added it from winform toolbox.So right now i'm a bit confused.

Can anyone shed some light.thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Component implementation that determines if something can appear in the toolbox is different for WinForms and WPF - which is why you don't see WinForms controls in the WPF toolbox, for example. In addition, this component is pretty old, so it's not really going to have the WPF version supported.

That said, nothing should prevent you from just creating an `AppUpdater` (I think, I didn't look at it too thoroughly) in your code without having the designer add one for you.